# Creating network bridge between main machine(windows) and ubuntu server(hp g3 800 sff without wireless compatibility) not working as expected

Tags: server, 22.04, ssh, windows, network-bridge

**URGENT** I have a windows main machine that connects to the internet via wifi and a ubuntu server that cannot connect to the internet via wifi as it does not have this capability. I have discovered creating a network bridge where the main machine(windows) essentially acts as a switch allowing the ubuntu server to have the ability to connect to the internet through it. Main goal is to ssh into the ubuntu server and control everything from there(updates, installation, running software etc). But for some reason after i follow the steps that I have read using online resources I am unable to ssh the ubuntu server nor ping it.

Here is the current setup of my network

1. Main machine(windows) connected to network via WIFI (has internet connectivity)
2. Main machine and ubuntu server connected directly to each other via an ethernet cable(cat 5e)
3. thats it, very simple network

on the ubuntu server side, I configured the file within the etc/netplan directory as follows to give server a static ip:

```
 network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.100/24
      routes:
         - to: default
           via: 192.168.0.1
```

On windows machine that already has a WIFI connection, I went to control panel>network and internet>network connections and selected the wireless wifi adaptor and ethernet adaptor by ctrl clicking on each and right clicked to create a network bridge.

For some reason the bridge does not work straight away and says "unidentified network" so had to disable each adaptor and renable each then network bridge has a internet connection.

Main machine still has internet connection as before but cannot ssh into ubuntu server from main machine command line via:

```
ssh server_name@192.168.0.100
```

nor can the server be pinged via `ping 192.168.0.100`, as states host is unreachable.

Been on this roadblock for a day and still cannot find a solution, so any help would do or try to recreate this on your own system and see if it works.